# How to open visual studio code from url

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, anchor

I'm followed [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_opening-vs-code-with-urls) to open a file from a URL in Visual Studio Code already provided:

And this is how I do it in my file:

```
<a href="vscode:/file/Users/abc/Desktop/about.html">Launch VS Code</a>
```

This opens the visual studio code but doesn't open the file.

What I need is to open the file in the editor along with the project in the IDE. Is there a way anyone knows to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a forward slash - `vscode://file` vs `vscode:/file`.

Comment: Thanks @Gama11, that opened my file in the editor. Is there any way I can open the project of this file as well? Like if this about.html file is in **mywebsite** directory, it opens that project for me in the editor as well?

Comment: I don't think so - as the docs say, you can either open a project folder or a single file. If you open a project, it restores the previously opened files in that project though.

Comment: Thanks @Gama11 for all the help!